# how to combine where condition and limit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI. Actually i want to fetch data from my product table. with multiple where conditions i.e. with specified menu_ids, but limit should be 1 for all means i want one product from each menu_id. Below is my model, it may be wrong. Please help.

```
My Model    

public function home_products(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('product');
            $this->db->where('menu_id', 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56);
            $this->db->where('product_status', 0);
            $this->db->limit('1');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
        }
```

Comment: I think you should have to remove `$this->db->limit('1');` and try to do as specified by @Akash.

Comment: I tried that, but now its showing all products related to their respective menu_ids

Comment: Try to add `$this->db->group_by('menu_id');` it might help.

Comment: Its working.. but as there are 6 menu_ids i need to add $this->db->limit('6'); also.. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

use $this->db->where_in('menu_id', array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56)); in place $this->db->where('menu_id', 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56);

Answer (score 0):

Try It:-

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where_in('menu_id', array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56));
    $this->db->where('product_status', 0);
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get('product');         
    return $query->result();
```

Refer [CI official doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) for more details.

Comment: updated my answer..Removed single quotes from `$this->db->limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->db->group_by('menu_id');` and

change

`$this->db->where('menu_id', 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56);`

to

`$this->db->where_in('menu_id', array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56));`.

Final Code is like this:

```
public function home_products(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('product');
    $this->db->where_in('menu_id', array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56));
    $this->db->where('product_status', 0);
    $this->db->group_by('menu_id');
    $this->db->limit('6');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```